# Unknown Provider error creating angular.js service with require.js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to get a service working using AMD loading with require.js. I have my controllers all working and can load $rootScope to store app-wide variables/data but I would also like to add some methods to modify or refresh some of the app-wide data when needed. Thus I was trying to create a service object in require.js

So I create this sort of a thing:

**MyService.js**

```
define( ["angular"], function (angular) {
    var MyService = function($scope, $rootScope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope
    }
    MyService.$inject = ["$scope"];
    MyService.prototype = {
        constructor: MyService,
        // comma separated list of methods and properties
    }
    return MyService
})
```

I similarly define a couple of controllers (all already working fine) then access them in my require.js config something like:

```
requirejs(
    [ "angular", "MyService", "MyController" ],
    function(angular, MyService, MyController) {
        let myAppHandle = angular.module('myApp',[])
            .service("myService", ['$scope','$rootScope', MyService])

        // the following throws an error:

        //     angular.js:15697 Error: [$injector:unpr]
        //         Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- myService

        myAppHandle.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService', MyController])
    }
)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check your controllers and make sure you injected ‘myService’ correctly

Comment: I posted my own answer - I was following examples for controllers that injected $scope - that turned out to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I was guessing in the dark at how to create a service properly in require.js and after some tinkering and banging my face on the keyboard, I eventually figured out the problem was not with the controller getting the service, but with the service getting $scope

The examples I found for require.js dealt mostly with controllers, components and directives and and in just about every case, $scope was the first thing passed in.

I took $scope out of the .service() in the definition and in the constructor for the class and it's now working.

```
define( ["angular"], function (angular) {
    var MyService = function($rootScope) {
        // using $rootScope to store app-wide variables
        //   accessible directly or via this service
        //   potentially updated/populated by methods in this service
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope
    }
    MyService.prototype = {
        constructor: MyService,
        // comma separated list of methods and properties
    }
    return MyService
})
```

and

```
requirejs(
    [ "angular", "MyService", "MyController" ],
    function(angular, MyService, MyController) {
        let myAppHandle = angular.module('myApp',[])
            .service("myService", ['$rootScope', MyService])

        myAppHandle.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService', MyController])
    }
)
```

for reference, this is what the controller looks like:

```
define( ["angular"], function (angular) {
    var MyController = function($scope, myService) {
        this.$scope = $scope
        // make service handle available as class property
        this.myService = myService
    }
    MyController.$inject = ["$scope"];
    MyController.prototype = {
        constructor: MyController,
        // comma separated list of methods and properties
    }
    return MyController
})
```

(Hopefully this will save someone else the 2-3 hours I took figuring this out)